# VBA: Weekly updated dashboard. Copy data for Trendline. EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I've managed to create an easy to update dashboard in Excel using VBA. It's pretty solid, but I require a weekly updated trendline to add to this data.

What i'd like is a macro that does the following:

1. Write data to range **X** (e.g. A1:A5)
2. Copy data from range **X** to Range **Y** (e.g. A10:A15)

And then when I run step 1 and 2 again

1. Write data to range **X**  (overwrite data in X A1:A5)
2. Copy Data from range **Y** to range **Y+1** (e.g. B10:B15)

repeat ad infinitum (each time moving one column to the right)

What I get is that i need to define the column line as an integer and then refer to it.
(e.g.

```
Sub Trend()

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1:A5").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Trendline data").Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False 

Sheets("Data").Select
i = i + 1

End Sub
```

However repeating this macro does not increment i for me.

*~~Also column 2 is filled completely with a repeat of the data in (Data!A1:A5)~~*
This is fixed with an update to the code.

Pretty much what I need to fix is that The line

```
 "Dim i As integer" 
 i = 2
```

becomes

```
"Dim i As integer" 
 i = 3
```

Permanently, and repeat the next time for i = 4, i = 5 etc.

After that for me it is easy to create a line chart from this range

Thank you.

edit: wrote what I thought would work, but apparently doesn't

Comment: That's a cool project. Now, what is your question? (Remember that Stack Overflow is not a free code request website..) Please look at those and edit your question accordingly : [help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [help/dont-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you Sifu. I will investigate and revise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited :**

What about that?

```
Sub Trend()

Dim i as integer

If Sheets("Data").Cells(1,1).Value = "" Then
    Sheets("Data").Cells(1,1).Value = 1
End if

i = Sheets("Data").Cells(1,1).Value


Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1:A5").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Trendline data").Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False 

Sheets("Data").Select


Sheets("Data").Cells(1,1).Value = i + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Sifu, However this doesn't work for me. What this does is fill Trendline data!A:E with a copy of Data!A1:A5. What I need is the macro to do the following: Select data in Data!A1:A5, Paste this data in Trendline Data!A1:A5. Stop. Then later when I have updated my dashboard there is new data in Data!A1:A5. I then want THAT data in Trendline Data!B1:B5.

Comment: Oh! Have a cell that you store the `i` value in. Ex : `Sheets("Data").Cells(1,1).Value = i` Then you grab the value at the beginning of your macro. You can always "Hide" that cell by applying white font on the cell so that it appears empty.

Comment: Simply adding that line keeps resetting `Data!A1` to "0" and then errors. Would it be possible to do an If statement on cell `Trendline data(1,i)` to see if it is empty. If true > paste. If false then do i + 1 and repeat.

Comment: @SebastiaanK My comment wasn't clear, I edited my answer to show what I meant. Does that help?

Comment: Keeps resetting `Data!A1` to 0.

Comment: @SebastiaanK Sorry I had a mistake (missing `Then` keywork for the if statement). This means that it was not saving (as it couldn't work properly). Try again now (I edited my answer) and see what it does. On my side (without the paste line), it adds +1 to cell A1 every time it is called.

Comment: Sifu, it works now. I will modify it further to suit my needs, but the basic algorithm is perfect. I'd upvote you, but I do not have enough reputation for that :( Thank you very much!